# Broke PHP and caused Wordpress white-screen on Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, fatal-error

I was doing some work on a wordpress site and another programmer had also been working on it. I was doing the design work, he was doing some custom PHP scripts. (we don't know each other.)

Some of his code was inserted in the wrong place and I made a few changes that I was confident I could undo if they broke the site. 5 hours later I go to log in and all admin screens are blank white. The site is still up and running though.

I tried to switch out the files I altered via ftp, but I must be forgetting something because it is still not working.

I checked the error log on the server and found one fatal error:

```
[01-Mar-2012 11:25:34] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home5/bestbik1/public_html/silvertoday/wp-content/themes/genesis/lib/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home5/bestbik1/public_html/silvertoday/wp-content/themes/streamline/functions.php on line 3
```

I am not experienced enough at PHP to know how to proceed to get the admin back up and working.

1. What does each part of this error mean specifically?
   and
2. What steps do I take to correct or troubleshoot?

---

**UPDATE**

Finally gave in and did a fresh install of the most recent version of the Genesis theme framework. Everything works again. Wanted to find the bug, but sometimes you gotta move on. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using a child theme of the [Genesis theme framework](http://www.studiopress.com/). Certainly, you've got a `functions.php` file in your "streamline" theme that's trying to include Genesis's `init.php`, which is normally the first line of any Genesis child theme's `functions.php`.

Assuming that your theme *is* a Genesis child theme, it looks like your Genesis theme install has become corrupt, with its `lib/init.php` missing or having the wrong permissions. I'd try removing the Genesis theme and reinstalling it (which may mean deleting and re-uploading the `wp-content/themes/genesis` folder.)

(You didn't uninstall the Genesis theme, did you? If you're using a Genesis child, Genesis has to be installed even if it's not the "active" theme.)

Comment: Thanks Matt! I checked and the file is there. I also tried switching permissions from 644 to 755, but that did not help. I can force the twenty-ten theme to kick in via FTP and that gets me into the dashboard. What process should I use to narrow down the problem code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if `/home5/bestbik1/public_html/silvertoday/wp-content/themes/genesis/lib/init.php` exists and is readable by the web server/PHP process, I can't think of any reason PHP would be telling you that it can't open the file. (Except maybe some odd .htaccess file hanging around that's restricting access somehow?)

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt. I gave in and did a fresh install of the newest copy of Genesis and it works again. Yay! I was holding out to try and find the bug, but finally had to just use a new copy.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that a required file :

```
/home5/bestbik1/public_html/silvertoday/wp-content/themes/genesis/lib/init.php
```

Could be not opened - there could be a number of reasons

1. The file is not present
2. The webserver does not have the correct permissions to read the file

I would first check that the file is present on the server in question.

Using the `require_once()` or `require` function in PHP means that is a required file cannot be opened the script is halted - this is the reason for the white screen.

Comment: Thanks ManseUK! The file appears to be there and I tried changing permissions without effect. What process should I use to narrow down the problem code?